# pip install for Windows Python interpreter on Kali Linux

Tags: linux, python, kali-linux, wine

I am trying to install [pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org) for the Windows Python interpreter on a Kali virtual machine.

Basically, I downloaded the latest version of Python 2.7 -> **python-2.7.16.msi**
and installed it from the terminal through:

```
wine msiexec /I python-2.7.16.msi
```

So far so good. If I go to `.wine/drive_c/Python 2.7` and run Python through `wine python.exe` everything works fine.

Now I need to install pyinstaller, but after I type (in the location reported before):

```
wine python.exe -m pip install pyinstaller
```

I get an error as reported below:

[image: Error message]

It is not clear to me if I have to install `pip` or if there is another issue. Anyhow, I am not sure how to install `pip` for the Windows Python interpreter.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `wine python.exe -m ensurepip -v`. It should have a line indicating where `pip` is installed (if it is at all).

Alternately (and in addition to), the `Scripts` directory of your Windows/Wine Python installation should contain `pip.exe` (along with other similarly named executables).

If e.g. `C:\Python27\Scripts` (note *not* e.g. `C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts`) doesn't exist or doesn't contain `pip.exe`, etc. under Wine, you may either wish to:

- Uninstall and reinstall Python under Wine, making sure any option to install `pip` is marked in the installer during the installation process.
- Follow the instructions given [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to download `get-pip.py`. Essentially, you would likely want to run:

  ```
    wine curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
  ```

Then you would want to run:

```
    wine python get-pip.py
```

*Notes*

- Reinstalling is probably preferable to using the `curl`/`get-pip.py` methods, since `get-pip.py` doesn't technically coordinate with the underlying "OS" (which should effectively be Wine, but Linux tends to be extremely dependant on Python).
- Official Windows builds of `curl` are available [here](https://curl.se/windows/), as needed, or for alternative unofficial builds, [here](https://curl.se/download.html).
- `wine python -m pip install -U pip` may be something else you want/need to run, regardless of anything else.